# $state.go inside $stateChangeStart in app.run not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

*NOTE: this is a sample code, the `window.has_redirected` is just to make the question easier.*

This code won't redirect to `dashboard`.

I've read online that the reason why it does't work is that `$state` is not ready yet.. however I'm seeing tutorials online that are doing something very similar to this.

How can I solve it?

```
(function(){
"use strict";

angular.module('app.routes').config( function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider ) {

    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');

    $stateProvider
    .state('login',{
        url: '/',
        ...
    })
    .state('dashboard', {
        url: '/dashboard',
        ...
    });


} ).run( function( $rootScope, Users, $state ) {
    $rootScope.$on( "$stateChangeStart", function(event, toState, toParams
                                                     , fromState, fromParams){

        if ( !window.has_redirected ){
            window.has_redirected = true;
            window.console.log('going to dashboard');
            $state.go('dashboard');
        }

    });
} );
})();
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is [a working plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/hUY6UIg5bgVMwh6fHQVa?p=preview)

You are almost there... What we really need here is to stop the execution flow with:

```
event.preventDefault();
```

which will stop the current state change, and will do redirect *(`$state.go()`)*:

```
$rootScope.$on( "$stateChangeStart", function(event, toState, toParams
                                                 , fromState, fromParams){

  // I would always check if we are not already on the way
  // to the "redirection" target. 
  var isGoingToDashboard = toState.name === "dashboard";
  if(isGoingToDashboard)
  {
    return;
  }

  // this remains
  if ( !window.has_redirected ){
      window.has_redirected = true;
      console.log('going to dashboard');

      // HERE is the essential breaker of the execution
      event.preventDefault();
      $state.go('dashboard');
  }
});
```

Check it in [action here](http://plnkr.co/edit/hUY6UIg5bgVMwh6fHQVa?p=preview)

Comment: Wow I can't believe how I forgot the event.preventDefault!
Thanks a lot for your great answer

Comment: If that helped great! Enjoy mighty UI-Router, sir ;)

Comment: Thanks @RadimKöhler :)